# Powershell core - regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell-core

Is there a problem with regular expressions in powershell. Running on Linux.
So, as an example.

```
PS> "Does this get found" | select-string -Pattern "^[A-Z ]*$"

Does this get found
```

But on bash shell

```
$ echo "Does this get found" | grep "^[A-Z ]*$"
$ echo "DOES THIS GET FOUND" | grep "^[A-Z ]*$"
DOES THIS GET FOUND
```

So regex acts differently. Is this a bug in powershell?

Comment: In your example there is no pattern. The RE is case insensitive by default, insert the property `-CaseSensitive`

Comment: I am sorry. I have edited the original.
And yes, you are right. Looking at about_regular_expressions man page, powershell treats all regex as case insensitive and so the -CaseSensitive is required. Which seems a bit daft as what is the use of all the features of regex?